# HTTP 500 (Internal server error) on concurrent MySQL requests through apache

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, load-testing, internal-server-error

I have setup a Wikipedia database where:

- One (1) host is running `mysqld`, running the database; I have installed the `mariadb-server` package.
- I have stored 16 million pages in 4 different tables (page, text, revision, redirect; each has 16 million rows, the latter about 7 million). Size of `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`: 88 GiB.
- Requests are served through an http server (`apache2`), using [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), just like in wikipedia.org.
- One single-threaded worker, on another machine, is sending 231 million requests to the database through http, with a timeout of 200-500 msec; many single requests time-out even at 200 msec.

The problem is, that most of the requests are not served due to "HTTP 500" (Internal Server Error). A few requests (100-200) are served without problems, but when launching requests with more than ~1'000 requests, then I receive an Internal Server Error on most occasions.

Here is a snapshot during an ongoing experiment:

- 38,086 requests: `HTTP 200 OK`.
- 1,200,226 requests: `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`
- 74,280 requests: timed out

In particular, here is a small excerpt from `/var/log/apache2/error.log` on the `mysqld` server:

```
[Mon Apr 18 02:42:43.492142 2016] [:error] [pid 70738] [client 172.16.96.23:41031] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/wikiadmin/mediawiki-1.26.2/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php on line 262
[Mon Apr 18 02:42:53.184116 2016] [:error] [pid 70665] [client 172.16.96.23:57976] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/wikiadmin/mediawiki-1.26.2/includes/parser/Preprocessor_DOM.php on line 1123
[Mon Apr 18 02:43:19.389313 2016] [:error] [pid 70745] [client 172.16.96.6:38824] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/wikiadmin/mediawiki-1.26.2/includes/Sanitizer.php on line 1087
[Mon Apr 18 02:43:22.188122 2016] [:error] [pid 69251] [client 172.16.96.6:55869] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/wikiadmin/mediawiki-1.26.2/includes/title/MediaWikiTitleCodec.php on line 377
[Mon Apr 18 02:43:38.404148 2016] [:error] [pid 70919] [client 172.16.96.6:60524] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/wikiadmin/mediawiki-1.26.2/includes/parser/Preprocessor_DOM.php on line 1124
[Mon Apr 18 02:43:42.188143 2016] [:error] [pid 69534] [client 172.16.96.6:51519] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/wikiadmin/mediawiki-1.26.2/includes/parser/Preprocessor_DOM.php on line 1119
[Mon Apr 18 02:42:23.004116 2016] [:error] [pid 70550] [client 172.16.96.23:35259] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/wikiadmin/mediawiki-1.26.2/includes/Message.php on line 260
```

I am looking for ideas on how to improve this situation from the server side by **serving more requests**. Being a complete newbie to MySQL and Databases in general, I have already conducted my research and came across different proposals, like (i) database sharding; (ii) MySQL cluster, etc; however, since so many proposals exist, I am not sure which direction I should take.

Is it a MySQL issue or a HTTP/MediaWiki issue?

Comment: the result is hardly a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

The task you are doing is called *load testing.* The results you see are well within the range of normal server behavior.

When a request times out, it means that your web server was too overloaded to respond to the request within the TCP/IP request timeout limit. That's controlled by the *client machine*: the machine you are using to make the requests to the Apache web server. The client machine retries a few times before giving up, in an operating-system dependent way. A Windows machine with standard configuration takes 72 seconds to give up.

Your 500 errors happen when the Apache server accepts a request, but then the media wiki code, written in PHP, doesn't complete before the 30 second limit. That limit is part of your PHP configuration. You can change it by editing your php.ini file. But it won't help. Your web server machine -- the machine running your Apache / PHP / mediawiki server is grossly overloaded and trying to do too many things at once. If you give the PHP more than thirty seconds to run, the server will simply try to do more things at once, and they'll all take longer.

I can't tell from your question whether you're using MySQL or MariaDb to host your database. But it doesn't matter. You're not getting errors telling you your database is buckling under this load.

It's your web server that's buckling under the load. It seems to be doing so gracefully ... In my experience the kind of load you are applying is perfectly capable of causing a hard crash of a web server. It looks like a successful load test to me: the test completed with timeouts but no crashes.

Ordinarily a system running the kind of production workload you're simulating uses multiple load-balanced web servers ( each Running Apache /PHP / mediawiki) that all use a single database. AWS Elastic Beanstalk is an example of a load balancing system. There are others.

Adding processor cores or RAM to your web server machine may also help a little, but it won't help much. You need multiple servers to scale out.

Somebody else suggested that you avoid wasting money and electricity on scaling your system to be much larger than you need for your actual usual workload. That is a wise suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is neither a mysql issue nor a HTTP/mediawiki issue. From the description of your problem it sounds like you don't have sufficient hardware to handle the amount of requests you are sending.

231 million request is a lot. A huge huge lot. Same goes for 1000 parallel requests. Do you seriously expect your site to get that many? if you do you will need to get suitable hardware for it.

Answer (score 1):

Apache takes more resources compared with some other http servers. Read https://serverfault.com/questions/7778/suggest-a-lightning-fast-feature-light-secure-linux-web-server-to-serve-static for choosing a better http server. You can enable opcache or use a php accelerator. Make sure you are using mysqli or pdo instead of mysql in php. Make sure you have enough ram on your servers, so data in ram don't have to be swapped out. Increase the buffer size of InnoDB. You can also use web services such as google app engine. Then you don't have to worry about the infrastructure yourself.